# Why didn't Obi Wan tell Luke that this character is his father?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a reason for this? Wouldn't that have been a helpful thing to say?

Comment: Because he's a *lying* schmuck.

Comment: The out-of-universe reason is that Vader didn't become Luke's father until ESB. When ANH released everything ObiWan said was true, not from a certain point of view but in general.